# Best way to read file and process content in java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, coding-style

I'm curious about the best way to read files and then process each line of the file. Assuming that the resource that needs to be read from can grow in size (e.g. a very large file) and the reading and processing of files can be swapped with a different implementation (e.g. reading an xml source instead of a file containing Strings).   Please consider the following approaches:

1. Create 2 services. First service is used to extract data from the file and return a list. Second service takes the list and iterate thru it to process each item. Pros for this approach is that it adheres to SRP and makes it posible to switch services(e.g. get the data from a different source like XML JSON).  The only con i could think about is that the performance hit of iterating thru the collection again (first time is when reading then putting in a collection) to do the processing.
2. Have only 1 service that will do both tasks.  This way you can do the processing inside the initial loop.  Trade offs would be the coupling between the reading and processing functionality which breaks the SRP.

If you have other suggestions on how to accomplish this all ideas are very welcome! TYIA!!!

Another thing i want to take away from this question is how great designers and developers (guys from this site ☺) come up with decisions for this case: why would you trade off one benefit for the other? best practices when comes to trade offs? Whats an acceptable trade off for you and why?Etc. Thanks again!

Comment: Use 2 threads in a *Producer-Consumer* fashion (blocking queue?) . As and how the producer thread puts data into a data structure, notify the consumer and let the consumer start its work.. This prevents race condition and improves performance.Also, clear the list(data structure) from time to time (after data is processed, you don't need it anymore)

Comment: 1. Your List might not fit in memory for a large file. 2. Processing one line at a time saves memory and allows you to process large files with trillions of lines.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks for the input. So in this use case are you saying that its ok to proiritize performance instead of a flexible design?

Comment: @TheLostMind if i understand correctly (and please correct me if im wrong), by using a producer-consumer design in this case will help in terms of memory management since you can control whats being loaded to the list right? So there is still that overhead of having to re-read the file everytime i need to update the list content and keep track of whats already in the list?

Comment: @Victor - Yes. The advantage of using this approach is that you need not store all the data and wait for it to be processed. The consumer will keep taking data from the queue / list and then process it. This way, less memory management.. Less GC kick-ins.. There will of course be a bottleneck.. Since you are doing IO.. The consumer will have to wait until  the producer fetches data... *So there is still that overhead of having to re-read the file everytime i need to update the list content and keep track of whats already in the list? * - I don't get this..

Comment: @TheLostMind I think i get what your saying, the producer thread will keep the IO open until the data has been exhausted right? I thought at first that  the producer will need to let go of the io everytime it loads data to the queue ☺ im not familiar with using the blocking queue in a producer-consumer design, i'll look into it thanks!

Comment: No.. You will have to keep the io open